# What's the relationship between Model and Array? It's complicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, eloquent

looking for Idea for making a relationship between Model and Array

if I have an array in helper run in a function like this example :

php

```
function color(){
$array = ['Black','Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue'];
return $array;
}
```

and have a table in my database return the key of values for array above

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('color', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->tinyIncrements('id');
        $table->tinyInteger('color_number');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

controller

```
    public function viewAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $id = $request->id;
        $info = Color::find($id);
        return response()->json($info);
    }
}
```

when view the output  I use if statement in jquery as ajax request

view

```
<label> user color: </label><span id="view_user_color"></span>


<script type="text/javascript">
function fun_view_color(id)
{
    var view_url = $("#hidden_view_color").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: view_url,
        type:"GET",
        data: {"id":id},
        success: function(result){
            function typeColor() {
                if (color === 0) {
                    $("#view_user_color").text("Black");
                } elseif(color === 1) {
                    $("#view_user_color").text("Red");
                }elseif(color === 2) {
                    $("#view_user_color").text("Orange");
                }elseif(color === 3) {
                    $("#view_user_color").text("Yellow");
                }elseif(color === 4) {
                    $("#view_user_color").text("Green");
                }elseif(color === 5) {
                    $("#view_user_color").text("Blue");
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

using if statement it's so bad and make the code too long

I am looking for batter way to do that

I know there is another way by making table contains colors and referenced by foreign key

but this is not my goal I need use array

Comment: Do you need the `color()` helper on the server side, or is it fine for it to be moved to Javascript instead?

Comment: both way will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function viewAjax(Request $request)
   {
    //include the helper function 
    $colors = color(); //array of colors
    if($request->ajax()) {
    $id = $request->id;
    $info = Color::find($id);
    $info->color = $colors[$info->color_number];
    return response()->json($info);
   }
```

}
And in the view

```
<label> user color: </label><span id="view_tower_color"></span>


    <script type="text/javascript">
       function fun_view_color(id)
      {
        var view_url = $("#hidden_view_color").val();
        $.ajax({
        url: view_url,
        type:"GET",
        data: {"id":id},
        success: function(result){
                    $("#view_user_color").text(result.color);
                          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: its work `text(result.color)` but `text(result.data.color)` didint work

Comment: Edited the answer to remove   data from result.data.color to have result.color. Happy for you  it is working.

Answer (score 1):

First, a joke: What's the relationship between Model and Array? It's complicated.

Thanks.

Now, you could use a lookup array for the helper (I renamed it to `colorMap()`). Consider this:

```
<?php

function colorMap() {

    // The keys match the color IDs you store in the database
    $array = [
        '0' => 'Black',
        '1' => 'Red',
        '2' => 'Orange',
        '3' => 'Yellow',
        '4' => 'Green',
        '5' => 'Blue'
    ];

    return $array;
}


<?php

public function viewAjax(Request $request) {

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $id = $request->id;
        $info = Color::find($id);

        // Pass an array containint the Color Model and the color map
        return response()->json([
            'color' => $info,
            'colorMap' => colorMap()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fun_view_color(id) {

        var view_url = $("#hidden_view_color").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: view_url,
            type:"GET",
            data: {"id":id},
            success: function(result) {
                setColorName(result);
            }
        });
    }

    function setColorName(result) {

        var colorId = result.info.id; // Passed from controller
        var colorName = result.colorMap[colorId]; // Passed from controller

        $("#view_user_color").text(colorName);

    }

</script>
```

Notes:

- The code doesn't use any validation, which you should provide
- This approach has a major flaw: if the color IDs will ever change, you'll
  need to change them anywhere they were hard-coded.
- You really should re-consider putting the colors into a table, instead.